# GraphQL: how to query items base on itemType AND itemId

Tags: sites-9.5, graphql

I would like to retrieve through GraphQL all the published URLs of a page, for all publicationIds.
Is there any way to retrieve items based on itemType (e.g., PAGE) and itemId (e.g., pageId="196")? (we are trying to avoid making one call per publicationId to get the page URLs)

Example:

```
{
  items(
      filter:{
          namespaceIds:[1],
          itemTypes:[PAGE], 
          publicationIds:[7,8,9], // all publications
          itemIds:[196] // something like this would be ideal
          }
      ) 
    {
        edges
        {
            node {
                itemId
                publicationId
                title
                ... on Page{
                    url
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have the ID already, why do you need to check if it is a page? Couldn't you just leave out "itemTypes:[PAGE]" ?